# How to change the home page and title in play template

Tags: playframework

I created a project using activator ui from "play2-crud-activator" template. I could not figure out how to change or from where the home page is being served.

The index.scala.html has below content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>play2-crud</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/app">CRUD index</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Now if i change the title to "alice inc" in the above page. Only the home page is reflecting it . localhost:9000/app still has the title "play2-crud" . I dont see a main.scala.html etc.

I could not find a place where the title is defined and could be changed. as there are no other html files in the directory.

Any help ?

Comment: Hmmm I don't know this template, but I can see that in `views/index.scala.html` there is `<title>play2-crud</title>`  hardcoded, so the title is always the same... give us more details (i.e. show us your view(s)), it's impossible to guess what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be inside the "views" folder from the root directory.

`views/index.scala.html`

Here are the contents of that file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>play2-crud</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/app">CRUD index</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks , but if i change that only home page is reflecting the new title , the subsequent pages served by "/app" still has the play2-crud. Edited the question, any help greatly apprecited

Comment: Looking in `conf/routes`, on the last line everything else not matched previously will use the routes file named play.crud.Routes. This file is in a dependency. In build.sbt, there is a dependency for `"play2-crud" %% "play2-crud" % "0.7.4-SNAPSHOT"`. Here is the source: http://hakandilek.github.com/maven-repo/snapshots/play2-crud/play2-crud_2.11/0.7.4-SNAPSHOT/play2-crud_2.11-0.7.4-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar. You can download the sources, extract to your own project to modify them locally, and remove those dependencies. You'll also need to copy the routes from play.crud.Routes to conf/routes.